# How to make JSON data from JSON.stringify accessible by PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

OK, so I need PHP to run through a bunch of URLs that are being dynamically generated by javascript. My only experience with getting data using PHP so far has been using a website's url that had JSON data directly available via an API.

So, after many painful hours of jumping through all sorts of different hoops, I've finally gotten my data to the point where I have the URLs and an id in perfect JSON syntax (thanks JSON.stringify()!). Now, I'd really like to point PHP to a url in order to start using this JSON....but how?!

I'm hesitant to post this, but a little push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. From what I'm looking at now, it seems like I may need to look more into POSTing this data to my server somehow? Should I be looking into AJAX?

Again, I know this is a real beginner question, so I'm looking more for slight nudges in the right direction rather than giving me a block of code that I need to use.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: After you stringify your JSON, you use AJAX to send it to PHP where you use json_decode to decode it into PHP array / object that you can work with.

Comment: Since you've said you're using jQuery in a comment below, I've added that tag.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to what you need to do:

1. Send the JSON to the server.
2. Decode the JSON into a PHP "associative array".

The first part can be done by submitting a form or using ajax to send a `POST` to the server. <s>If you're not using any libraries, you'd use [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) to do that, but all of the major JavaScript libraries have convenience functions to make it easier. Since the easiest way to send the JSON string to the server is by using the standard multipart form data encoding, be sure to encode the JSON string using `encodeURIComponent`. So for example:</s>

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Older browers may need some special handling when creating the object
xhr.open("POST", "/path/to/your/page");
xhr.send("jsondata=" + encodeURIComponent(yourJsonString));
```

Since you've said you're using jQuery, you can use [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to post the data to the server:

```
$.ajax({
    url:     "/path/to/your/page.php",
    type:    "POST",
    data:    {jsondata: yourJsonString},
    success: function(data) {
        // Handle successful post here, use `data` if your PHP
        // page sends a reply
    },
    error:   function() {
        // Handle error here
    }
});
```

The second part (receiving the JSON and decoding it) is done by accepting the POST variable (`jsondata` in the above) and decoding it via [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Hm, I need a bit of help with the /path/to/your/page part (I'm using jQuery, but it's still the URL that I'm not quite sure I'm grasping). Am I specifying the PHP page with the url? Or am I specifying some blank file that will then be filled with the POSTed JSON data (similar to the JSON API that I dealt with)? Or none of the above?

If it is the PHP page, how do I reference the JSON data besides using json_decode? json_decode(stringifiedarray) where stringifiedarray is the name of the array in my .js file?

Comment: @Kris: The `/path/to/your/page` is the path to the PHP page that will receive and process the JSON data. Since you're using jQuery, I've updated the answer.

Comment: When I made my first php page, I used this at the beginning to bring in the JSON and get it working: 
`$json = file_get_contents("http://api.link.com/etc");

$elements = json_decode($json);`

But I'm not sure exactly how to start out now. Would I self reference using $json = file_get_contents(test.php) and $elements = json_decode($json), where test.php is the url I POSTed to with my ajax query? 

I am a complete noob at PHP and honestly don't even know how to do basic checks like whether the JSON data is loading correctly, so sorry about bouncing such rudimentary questions off of you!